# How to locate ng-model within a div element in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help with trying to locate an element with `ng-model="error-message"`. This element is within a div element. I am using selenium with C#.

```html
<label ng-model="errorMessage" class="text-danger message_container ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-not-empty">
    Error while creating instance from import file: Error: End of data reached (data length = 0, asked index = 4). Corrupted zip ?
</label>
```

The value of the element changes based on button click and file upload window event. Below is the html code of the page.

Comment: Can you consider sharing your work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C#, but can you use a `css`-selector find the element with the `css`-selector, something like `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector('[ng-model="errorMessage"]'));`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below locator solves your query:

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label[ng-model='errorMessage']"));